# criteria sorting/index

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of accounts for attendance for each day the employee is in an "X" will be marked on that day as the following picture

[image]

I have the following criteria per account 
[image]

If the account has a X for 5 days in a row, I want to log its ID in a summary tab as the following 
as seen in the pictures if the X is 5 days in a row (colored in the pic) I need to log it if less than 5 days then no log needed and "no is written"

I need something to compare the values under the dates every 5 days such as :
01/11/2018 to 05/11/2018 and then from 02/11/2018 to 06/11/2018

I don't know nothing about VBA but could someone just attach something where I can read about it so I do it and if there is a formula for such things just attach the link to the basic concept and ill read about it and turn it to what I need

I just need someone to give me the basic headline and ill do the rest because I cannot find nothing related to this on google 
[image]

Comment: Why not start with =COUNTIF(A1:E1,"x")>5 and then control things from there?

Comment: ive tried that but you need to know on which days the criteria was met

Comment: Then you need to give us an idea of what you have tried so we don't waste our time...

Comment: I use this one =IF(AND($B2="negative",$C2="negative",$D2="negative",$E2="negative",$F2="negative"),"negative",IF(B2="no history","no history","positive"))

Comment: and I used this one too =INDEX('Apply Fourmlas'!$G:$G,MATCH('Apply fourmlas2'!$A:$A,'Apply Fourmlas'!$A:$A,0)) but the problem they take the 5 days like this format 1-5 then 5-10 it doenst work as this 1-5 then 2-6 etc..

Comment: for each id are there 3 rows?
for how long do you want to do a control on the dates?